# JFormattedTextField with a maskFormatter throws NumberFormatException

Tags: java, swing, parsing, input, integer

I have a JFormattedTextField using the following mask formatter:

```
    private MaskFormatter maskForInput;
    maskForInput=new MaskFormatter("####"); // I have tried using stars (*) too.
    maskForInput.setValidCharacters("0123456789");

    javax.swing.JFormattedTextField playerRaiseField=new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(maskForInput);
```

This is supposed to allow the user to enter up to 4 digits as an input. However when I am trying to `Integer.parseInt(playerRaiseField.getText())` the `String` returned from this field I am always getting a `NumberFormatException` possibly due to the empty spaces left on user input.
To clear this up:

If the user inputs `560` for example there is a trailing space left behind so the String I am reading is `560( )` and when trying to parse this `String` into an `int` this exception is thrown. Any workarounds? How can I modify the mask formatter to accept 1 to 4 digits and *not* always 4 digits fixed??

**Note:** Curiously enough using `trim()` on the `String` returned is still not removing the extra whitespace character...

Comment: if you print out the string between quotes, what do you get?

Comment: @Jake223 I am getting 4 empty spaces. Now that's weird...

Comment: See the documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html specially for placeholder character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your expectations...

Firstly, you seem to believe that a formatted field can have any number of characters.  This isn't true (while you can get the text, the field remains in what it considers to be an invalid state).  The formatted field expects that the all the places of the mask must be filled.

Secondly, you should be using the `JFormattedTextField#getValue` method to return the value of the field, not `getText`

Thirdly, the text being returned is filled with the mask's placeholder character (`MaskFormatter#getPlaceholder`), which may or may not be a space, so `String#trim` probably isn't going to be of help...

If you want the user to only be able to enter a numeric value, which may consist of 0-n characters, then you really should consider using a `DocumentFilter` applied to normal `JTextField`

```
public class TestField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestField();
    }

    public TestField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class NumericDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        private int maxChars;

        public NumericDocumentFilter(int maxChars) {
            this.maxChars = maxChars;
        }

        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                String text, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(text);
            for (int i = buffer.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                char ch = buffer.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                    buffer.deleteCharAt(i);
                }
            }

            text = buffer.toString();
            if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length() > maxChars) {
                int remaining = maxChars - fb.getDocument().getLength();
                text = text.substring(0, remaining);
            }

            if (text.length() > 0) {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
                int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (length > 0) {
                fb.remove(offset, length);
            }
            insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField field;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            field = new JTextField(4);
            ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new NumericDocumentFilter(4));
            add(field);
            field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(field.getText());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not sure how you used trim, I will suggest you to try following line of code to remove space :
   As discussed following code should work :

```
String playerBet=playerRaiseField.getText();
// if playerBet is not null
String playerBetWithoutSpaces=playerBet.trim();

Integer.parseInt(playerBetWithoutSpaces);
```

Comment: That's not the case, I first store the value returned by `getText()` to a String and use `.trim()` on this `String`. This will likely make no change, but thanks for help.

Comment: `String playerBet=playerRaiseField.getText();` and then  `playerBet.trim();`

Comment: and then what are you passing to Integer.parseInt ?? just playerBet ,, if yes,, than that is problem

Comment: Yeap, just `playerBet`. What is the problem?

Comment: try following,, it will work Integer.parseInt(playerBet.trim());

Comment: Problem is that trim() will not change playerBet, it will just return value of playerBet after removing spaces, that you need to capture in another variable.

Answer (score 0):

### [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html#setMask%28java.lang.String%29)

1

```
public void setMask(String mask)
             throws ParseException
```

---

2  You say you get 4 blank spaces. That means there's no default value set and you're not using invalidcharacters. Look up the above documentation.

3 For making it scalable (1-4) you have to determine the length of the input and then make run it through a proper mask with IFs. You could also fill the remaining mask with a default value, see the documentation.

EDIT: see you posted more code below. You don't do getText on an existing string. You use that to get input from fields. You have to do it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Your format "####" allows only exactly 4 digits. For variable length you would have to write a custom class. [here](http://windowkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/org/windowkit/toolkit/widget/text/PhoneNumberMaskFormatter.java) is an example class.

I implemented something using your code and it worked for me only when all 4 numbers were filled in:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class tes implements ActionListener
{
  public static JFormattedTextField playerRaiseField;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
JFrame j=new JFrame();
    j.setSize(400,400);
    j.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

MaskFormatter maskForInput;
    maskForInput=new MaskFormatter("####"); // I have tried using stars (*) too.
    maskForInput.setValidCharacters("0123456789");

    playerRaiseField=new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(maskForInput);
j.getContentPane().add(playerRaiseField);
JButton jb=new JButton("Print out the above value");
j.getContentPane().add(jb);
jb.addActionListener(new tes());
j.setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("\""+Integer.parseInt(playerRaiseField.getText())+"\"");
}
}
```

Comment: Yeap it works with 4 numbers but not for any less, that's my problem.